# Scheduled batch job is queue and aborted

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a schedulable class and am using a cron value to reschedule the job every 15 minutes. It has been working, but all the sudden stopped. I checked the apex jobs and the scheduler reschedules every 15 minutes, shows queued, never runs, gets aborted and rescheduled. I thought it was a time zone issue. My user was in CST and the system ran in EST. So, I updated my user to EST and rescheduled the job, but it is still queuing, aborting and rescheduling (never runs). I cannot figure out what is causing this to happen.

Here is my schedulable class:

```
    global class OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler implements Schedulable {

      Boolean cacheLoaded = false;

      private BusinessHours getDefaultBusinessHours() {
        BusinessHours bh = new BusinessHours();
        if(cacheLoaded) return bh;
        bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
        cacheLoaded = true;
        return bh;
      }

        global static String scheduleIt() {
            datetime nextScheduleTime = system.now().addMinutes(15);
            integer minute = nextScheduleTime.minute();
            integer second = nextScheduleTime.second ();
            integer hour = nextScheduleTime.hour();
            integer year = nextScheduleTime.year(); 
            integer month = nextScheduleTime.month(); 
            integer day = nextScheduleTime.day();
            string cronvalue = second + ' ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' + year;
            string jobName = 'Self Rescheduling Order Approval Deadline Scheduler ' + nextScheduleTime.format('hh:mm');

            OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler scheduler = new OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler();
            return system.schedule(jobName, cronvalue, scheduler);
        }

      global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        BusinessHours bh = getDefaultBusinessHours();
        Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c> recordsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c>();
        for(Order_Approvals__c oa : [select Approval_Deadline__c, Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c from Order_Approvals__c where Response__c = NULL]) {
          if(system.now() >= oa.Approval_Deadline__c) {  
            oa.Approval_Deadline__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, oa.Approval_Deadline__c, 32400000);
            oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c = oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c + 1;
            recordsToUpdate.put(oa.Id, oa);
          }
        }
        if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            List<Database.Saveresult> results = Database.update(recordsToUpdate.values(), false);
            for(Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
                if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                        // process any errors here 
                        system.debug(err.getMessage());
                        system.debug(err.getStatusCode());
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
        try { 
            system.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId()); 
        } 
        catch (exception e) {
            system.debug('************ schedule job exception while aborting: ' + e);
        }
        system.debug('************* schedule job executing'); 
        scheduleIt();
      }
```

I can't figure out why it has been working without any issue for over a year and then stopped and now fails to run after I execute the code in the anonymous window to schedule it and have it run normally.

Comment: How many active batch jobs do you have at any given time? Reason I ask is because there is a limit to how many active jobs are running.
Maximum number of batch Apex jobs queued or active concurrently is five.  
Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: @DoubleA That is an excellent point. I just ran the following query in dev console: `SELECT COUNT() FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'` I got a count of 3 so it doesn't appear to be the governor limit unless that is not the correct query, but I pulled it from the Apex Scheduler documentation.

Comment: Your org would have been recently updated to Spring 17 and the job could be "stuck" as a result of having been in the process of loading during the update of your instance. See if you can "kill" all instances of the job and then restart it. If you can't, you'll need to file a case with Salesforce. This and similar are known issues with Schedulables when you don't use a new instance of them via a virtual class.